# DropDown bind to property names; based on first set second DropDown binding

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have one `ObservableCollection<M> fooBar {get;set;}`. The class `M.cs` looks like this:

```
public class M{
    private int _ID;
    public int ID {
        get {return this._ID;}
        set {this._ID = value;}
    }

    private string _number;
    public int Number {
        get {return this._number;}
        set {this._number = value;}
    }

    private string _power;
    public int Power {
        get {return this._power;}
        set {this._power = value;}
    }

    /*
       ...
    */
}
```

Now I want to bind the names of these 3 propertys to a `ComboBox`. I don't want to do it like this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>ID</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Number</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Power</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Is there a more comfortable way?

Based on the choose of the first `ComboBox` I want to fill the second `ComboBox`. As example I choose in the first `ComboBox` the property `Number`then the second `ComboBox` should look like this

```
<ComboBox
    SelectedValue="{Binding ???}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding fooBar}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Number" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Number"
    />
```

Maybe someone of you can help me, because I have no idea how to connect both comboboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

- Make a property on the view model which exposes the properties on the model (class M) which can be selected. This way you explicitly control which properties can be selected.
- Make a property to hold the selected value of each combo box.
- DisplayMemberPath/SelectedValuePath in ComboBox2 binds to the SelectedValue of ComboBox1.

ViewModel:

```
        // ComboBox 1
        public Dictionary<string, string> SelectableProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { nameof (M.ID), "ID" }
            { nameof (M.Number), "Nummer" }
            { nameof (M.Power), "Potenz" }
        }

        // Selection in combobox 1 (not strictly necessary as it can be handled in view, but you may need to know what SelectedValue represents)
        private string _selectedValueMember = String.Empty;
        public string SelectedValueMember
        {
            get { return _selectedValueMember; }
            set { _selectedValueMember = value; }
        }

        // Selection in combobox 2 (object just in case there could be other values than int) 
        private object _selectedValue = null;
        public object SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _selectedValue; }
            set { _selectedValue = value; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<M> FooBar{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1"
                  Width="100"
                  Margin="5"
                  SelectedValuePath="Key"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValueMember}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableProperties}">

        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Width="100"
                  Margin="5"
                  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedValue}"
                  SelectedValuePath="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedValue}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FooBar}">

        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: THanks for the answer @sondergard ! I have one problem. I don't want to show all properties and I want translate them into german. How can I do that?

Comment: Localizing can be done using a dictionary where the value part is the localized text, and having the selectedvaluepath/displaymemberpath point to key/value respectively. I have update the sample with my best guess according to my recollection of german (it's been, what, 15 years?) :) You could of course use strings from a resource also if you want.

Comment: thanks alot! Now it works. Never used `Dictionary` befor. ^^

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st ComboBox: Use Reflection to get the names of all the properties of class M and put those into the ComboBox.

For the 2nd ComboBox: When selection changes in the 1st one, you get the property name. Now set the SelectedValue binding to the property that was selected in the 1st ComboBox.